# Templates for "notes-examples-... environment"

Tags: templates

Books often use special environments to display examples, theoretical details, notes, etc. 
Here is one example:
[image]

Do you know any website that collects templates for this kind of special environments (something similar to "[beamer theme gallery](http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/)" but for "notes environments")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any website that collects templates of theorem-like environments. But see the manuals of [mdframed](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed) and the [ntheorem](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ntheorem) packages for examples. You can also search this site for examples of the use of these packages. Here are lists for [`mdframed`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=mdframed) and [`ntheorem`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=ntheorem).